# iOS - writing a callback outside the implementation scope

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to register a callback to send in to

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener
```

which notifies you when there has been an audio property change (for example, headphones being unplugged).

In the [iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AddMusic/Listings/Classes_MainViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Classes_MainViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6), and also [here in another forum](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54013-hardware-volume-change-listener-callback.html), it is shown that you can put code outside of the implementation block, and use a call to get the ViewController, so you can access instance variables.

a simple example, would be this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
                                   void                      *inUserData,
                                   AudioSessionPropertyID    inPropertyID,
                                   UInt32                    inPropertyValueSize,
                                   const void                *inPropertyValue
                                   ) {

ViewController *controller = (ViewController *) inUserData;

}


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

@end
```

So in the callback, its telling me I need to bridge the call to get ViewController.  If I do this, I then cant access certain variables.  The weird thing is, I've downloaded the iOS sample (linked above) and this complies in that case.  What am I doing wrong here??

### Edit:

If I DO bridge the call to get an instance of controller, I will get this

```
ViewController *controller = (__bridge ViewController *) inUserData;
int isPlaying = controller->appSoundPlayer.playing;
```

and I get an error that appSoundPlayer is protected. I believe there is a way to do this without bridging, because as I said, apples example somehow compiles, but I dont see what I am doing differently

Comment: Can you give us examples of which variables you aren't able to access? Since the callback function is outside the scope of the class, you can't access any ivars of the ViewController object unless you're using an accessor method.

Comment: Ok, I added an edit.  appSoundPlayer is definied in the interface in ViewController.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C instance variables are `@protected` by default, so you
cannot access them from outside the class.

You *could* solve this by declaring the instance variable as `@public`.

The recommended solution however is to make `appSoundPlayer` a `@property`
and access it as `controller.appSoundPlayer.playing`.

The bridging cast looks OK.

Comment: This does seem to work.  I will will accept and up-vote when I test it out in its entirety.  Any other ideas about why I could compile this in one project without the cast, just as a piece of mind?

Comment: @Jameo: Yes, the bridging casts are required if you compile with *Automatic Reference Counting*. See "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes" for more information.

Comment: Ah, I thought that the sample used ARC.  This is definitely the source of confusion from the start. Thanks for the help!